# How to get Transparent Background in VI Editor?

Tags: gvim, gui, vi

I am using gvim in Windows and novice to it.

I want to have a transparent background for my VI (in Windows) , like console which creates a transparent command prompt.

I asked the same question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270217/how-to-get-transparent-background-in-vi-editor) and someone redirected me to here.

Comment: I doubt there is such thing on the Windows version, but if there is, I'm interested too.

Comment: emacs23 on windows (has transparency) plus viper mode :)

Answer (score 3):

Run it (vim, not gvim) in [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) and learn a few VIM commands like, :w for save. (esc :w if you're editing something.)

Comment: And what suggests you that he "should learn" that ? GVim is the easiest for windows, as you can edit directly a file with it (with a context menu shortcut, for example). It's not only used by people who "can't" use vim in a console.

Comment: @Gnoupi I don't see any reason not to...Well I'm a developer so what do I know...

Answer (score 0):

This capability would have to be added to gvim, as it does not have it.

There is a [patch for background images in gvim](https://web.archive.org/web/20090609161605/http://www.jbrowse.com/text/bmbk.shtml) which you might enjoy.

Also, there is a program called [Glass2k](http://chime.tv/products/glass2k.shtml) which allows you to make any Windows program transparent.  It will make the whole window transparent, not just the background.

Answer (score 0):

Just installed this and it's working really well for me.

https://github.com/mattn/transparency-windows-vim